# Copy Exchange Database from Passive to Active

Tags: exchange, exchange-2007, replication, transaction-log, database-replication

I have a CCR running with a total of 6 servers 2 MB, 2HT, 2 CAS.

I had a failure on active node this morning and everything failed to my passive server, i had some issues with the logs, as the werent replicating to the passive, which made sense since the active server failed because of a backup that was running on the exchange system, so the logs didnt trunk and passive and active didnt have the same logs, so no problem right? just reseed.... so i got everything working and i was about to start reseeding, then something happen, the cluster failover to his primary server making the passive a passive node again!! my problem now, is that i deleted the transaction logs and Database from the active node ( which was the passive after the failover) so i have a good database on the passive node, how do i re-seed from passive to active? i know that you re-seed onlye to passive from active... what options do i have here?

I was thinking on check the status of the database, if i have a clean shutdown, can i copy the edb to the active and try to mount the db?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It does work, just make sure to run eseutil, and verify that you DB is on clean state, also make a copy before you do anything to the DB, including eseutil.